# Add condition dependency to the job

Tags: java, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I'm trying to add condition dependency to the job but my modification isn't visible in TWSz AD:

```
    JobStream jobStream = new JobStream();
//... new job stream code
Job job01 = new Job();
job01.setName("1");
job01.setPriority(1);
//...first job ZOSJobDefinition
JobKey job01Key = (JobKey)job01.getKey();
jobStream.getJobs().add(job01);
Job job02 = new Job();
//...econd job code
//internal dependency to the first job
InternalDependency job02tojob01 = new InternalDependency(null, job01Key);
job02.getInternalDependencies().add(job02tojob01);
JobKey job02Key = (JobKey)job02.getKey();
Job job03 = new Job();
//job03 code
//job03 ZOSJobDefinition
//job03 internal dependency to first job
InternalDependency job03tojob01 = new InternalDependency(null, job01Key);
job03.getInternalDependencies().add(job03tojob01);
//ConditionalDependency
ConditionalDependency condDep = new ConditionalDependency();
ConditionalJobDependency condJob03toJob02 = new ConditionalJobDependency();
condJob03toJob02.setAbstractJobKey(job02Key);
condJob03toJob02.setConditionCheckType(ConditionCheckType.STATUS_TYPE);
condJob03toJob02.setConditionLogicalOperatorType(ConditionLogicalOperatorType.NE_TYPE);
condJob03toJob02.setConditionStatus(ConditionStatus.COMPLETED_STATUS);
condDep.getConditionalJobDependencies().add(condJob03toJob02);
job03.getConditionalDependencies().add(condDep);
model.addTWSObject(jobStream, null);
```

JobStream with jobs and internal dependencies are added correctly anlu Conditional dependencies are not visible in scheduler. how it should be done properly?

Comment: Hi, in the code above job2 and job3 are not added to the jobStream.getJobs() list. Do you see them added? maybe the code is not complete.

Do you get an error or conditional dependencies are just ignored?

Comment: Hi Franco, you are right I have missed add job3 to the jobStream but when I added it TWS returned:AWSJCS011E An internal error has occurred. The error is the following: "java.lang.NullPointerException".

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of your TWS env

Condition dependencies is available on version 9.3.0.3

Comment: 9.4 and I am able to set conditional dependencies using ISPF panels and IWS